# Ubuntu server 10.04 ESXi 4 VMTools install?

Tags: server, vmware

Am struggling to install vmtools on a ubuntu 10.04 server guest on my esxi server.  I have tried the "Install VM Tools" option but that does nothing.  I have tried running the apt-get install vmware-tools but get the message that there are no packages.  Has anyone managed to do this as it is driving me nuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the "Install VM Tools" action a virtual media should be available from the cdrom from the guest OS (the cdrom is attached to the vmware tools iso).
Because you are using a server install (no cdrom auto mount magic) you will need to manually mount the cdrom:

```
sudo mkdir /mnt/cdrom
sudo mount /dev/cdrom /mnt/cdrom
```

Check the contents from /mnt/cdrom, there is a binary that you will need to execute to install the tools (I don't have vmware installed right now to check).

Comment: This is what happens when trying to do work stuff late at night after a full day!  thanks very much for the nudge in teh right direction!